# How to change the question number from just '1' to 'Question No. 1.' in the book class?

Tags: exsheets

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{exclist}{default}{
  runin = true ,
  number-post-code = \space ,
  attach = { main[r,vc]number[l,vc](-1em,0pt) } ,
  above = 0pt,
  below = 0pt 
}

\SetupExSheets{
%%  solution/print = true , 
  headings = exclist ,
  headings-format = \bfseries, 
  counter-within = chapter
}

\usepackage{scrextend}% needed with a KOMA-Script class, `addmargin' environment

\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-hook = \addmargin[1em]{0em} ,
  question/post-hook = \endaddmargin ,
  solution/pre-hook = \addmargin[1em]{0em} ,
  solution/post-hook = \endaddmargin
}





\begin{document}

\section{one}

\begin{question}
    This is sample question 1.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    This is sample solution 1. 
\end{solution}
\vfill

\vfill
\begin{question}
    This is sample question 2.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    This is sample solution 2. 
\end{solution}
\vfill

\newpage
\printsolutions



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-format=No. qu[],
  headings-format = \bfseries, 
  counter-within = chapter,
  headings=runin,
  question/name = Question
}


\begin{document}

\section{one}

\begin{question}
    This is sample question 1.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    This is sample solution 1. 
\end{solution}
\vfill

\vfill
\begin{question}
    This is sample question 2.
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
    This is sample solution 2. 
\end{solution}
\vfill

\newpage
\printsolutions



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Thanks to [@Clemens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351922/how-to-change-the-question-number-from-just-1-to-question-no-1-in-the-book/351939?noredirect=1#comment865192_351939) for his useful comments!

Comment: `\RenewQuSolPair{question}[name=Question]{solution}` is a complicated way of saying `\SetupExSheets{question/name = Question}` or `\SetupExSheets{question/type = exam}`. Also, `counter-format = No.\,qu ,` would suffice, no need for braces or brackets.

Comment: @clemens Thanks for your useful comments --  and for the great package! The documentation is very well structured!